# Java string to object's List

Tags: java, android, json, string

How is it possible to get List object from String, add new element to list and turn it back to string. I use Json and jackson, created class for list's element:

```
public class WeightDataJson {
        private String weightValue;
        private String dateValue;
        public WeightDataJson(String weightValue,String dateValue){
            this.weightValue=weightValue;
            this.dateValue=dateValue;
        }
        public String getWeightValue() {
            return weightValue;
        }
        public void setWeightValue(String weightValue) {
            this.weightValue = weightValue;
        }
        public String getDateValue() {
            return dateValue;
        }
        public void setDateValue(String dateValue) {
            this.dateValue = dateValue;
        }
    }
```

and my code for change List and String:

```
                String myWeightData = preferencesWeight.get();
                List<WeightDataJson> myList = new Vector<WeightDataJson>();
                ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                try {
                    myList = jsonMapper.readValue(myWeightData, new TypeReference<List<WeightDataJson>>(){});
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                WeightDataJson newWeightData = new WeightDataJson(editText.getText().toString(),"213123");
                myList.add(newWeightData);

                JSONObject myJson=new JSONObject();
                for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
                    try {
                        myJson.put("weightValue",myList.get(i).getWeightValue());
                        myJson.put("dateValue",myList.get(i).getDateValue());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                String toSave ="["+myJson.toString()+"]";
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"zapisuje: "+toSave,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                preferencesWeight.save(toSave);
                WeightDataProvider weightDataProvider = new WeightDataProvider(addIcon,deleteIcon,editText.getText().toString(),"213123");
                weightAdapter.add(weightDataProvider);
```

`myWeightData` is 'basic' String (this is possible that it is empty), I am not sure but probably there is problem because String for jakcson has to be like `[{element1},{element2}]` and Json object gives `{element1},{element2}` so I put there `String toSave ="["+myJson.toString()+"]"`.

If basic String is `[{weightValue":"50","dateValue":"34234"}]` I have an error in line `myList=jsonmapper.readValue~~`:

```
07-30 03:59:04.407 11837-11837/com.plan.aplikacjamobilna W/System.err: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.plan.aplikacjamobilna.WeightDataJson]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
07-30 03:59:04.407 11837-11837/com.plan.aplikacjamobilna W/System.err:     at [Source: [{"weightValue":"14","dateValue":"213123"}]; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding a default constructor like the error message said it's missing?

Comment: Do you mean constructor for WeightDataJson?

Comment: Yes.  You haven't defined a default constructor for that class, and java won't automatically create one if you've already defined any of your own.  I expect jackson is trying to create a blank object and then inject values into it, which it can't do without a default constructor.

Comment: I tried `public WeightDataJson(){}` but there is the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want store data as String Why are you complicating things and involving other unnecessary classes and object of those ?

1. override method toString() in your class

   a) chose data(variable) **delimiter1** *":"*

   b) concatenate data for Class records (variables) using delimiter1
2. make constructor with String parameter to:

   a) split concatenated string with previous used delimiter1

   b) assign result [] of split to declared variables
3. make static methods to:

   a) List<> as parameter to concatenate each object toString() method produced strings with **delimiter2** *"%"* to achieve something like this:

   ```
    "var1o1:var2o1%var1o2:var2o2%var1o3:var2o3" etc
   ```

   b) to split above string with:

   ```
   b.a/ delimieter2  - > then result each String pass to object to split with

   b.b/ delimieter1 -> then result [] of split assign to variables
   ```

Comment: Hmm I am doing it first time and im not sure what should be in toString() method, could you help me please?

Comment: @barmi I would recommend that you not use toString() for your serialization purposes. toString() is supposed to be a human-readable representation of your class instances and generally not supposed to be intelligently parsed by your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to switch between your type and String. Usage:

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

**From POJO to String:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(weightData);
```

**From String to POJO:**

```
WeightDataJson newWeightData = gson.fromJson(json, WeightDataJson.class);
```

**EDIT :**

**With ArrayList**

```
List<WeightDataJson> list = new ArrayList<WeightDataJson>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);
list.add(obj3);
..
Type type = new TypeToken<List<WeightDataJson>>() {}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(list, type);
List<WeightDataJson> newWeightData = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: The OP isn't trying to parse a single `WeightDataJson`, but a `List` of `WeightDataJson`.